# "mate-network-properties" won't honor ignored-hosts address

Tags: networking, mate, hosts

I want to block a social media address.

When I block it via

```
  echo "127.0.0.1     facebook.com" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null
```

works.

But when I use `mate-network-properties` gui and add `127.0.0.1     facebook.com` into `ignored-hosts` tab, it ignores the address I added, I mean it doesn't block that address. I also ran `mate-network-properties`
as sudo but nothing's changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mate-network-properties` GUI focuses on the Proxy settings:

[image: Network Proxy Preferences]

The values that are entered into "Ignored Hosts" will not run through the proxy connection. This is why the three `localhost` addresses are pre-filled in, as there's no point running any of those through a proxy server.

If you would like to block network traffic to Facebook (or any other service), then the simplest methods would be through the use of a `hosts.deny` file. Here's how you can set one up:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create the `hosts.deny` file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/hosts.deny
   ```
2. Add records in this format:

   ```
   ALL : .domain.com
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Do not forget that preceding `.` in front of the domain.</sup>
3. Save the file
4. There is no fourth step

What's nice about this method is that you can create a single list that gets shared across multiple devices through a regular sync process. No muss. No fuss.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `gnome-network-admin` tool had an option to edit `etc/hosts` file in the earlier version of Ubuntu